# How can I create a right click behaviour within an operator to override the default contextual menu for buttons in my panel?

Tags: operator

I've created a panel with a button and have figured out how to use modal checks to check if the user was holding ctrl, shift etc while clicking the button. I'd also like to replace the default contextual menu that appears when the user right clicks the button in my panel. So far I haven't been able to figure that out so I was wondering if anyone with more experience might be able to point me in the right direction?

I've simplified this code to show what works and what doesn't in my current code. When I run this, the console prints everything as expected except for print("Right clicked"). Is there a different way of trying to detect right clicks? And even if I do manage to detect the right click, is it even possible for me to replace the default contextual menu in my panel?

Thanks for any help

````
import bpy

class myPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = "my_panel"
    bl_label = "My panel"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "Test"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("object.my_modal_operator", text = "Test")

class myModalOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """My modal operator"""
    bl_idname = "object.my_modal_operator"
    bl_label = "Modal operator"
        
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None
        
    def invoke(self, context, event):
        if event.type == 'RIGHTMOUSE':
            print("Right clicked")
        elif event.ctrl:
            print("Ctrl pressed")
        elif event.shift:
            print("Shift pressed")
        else:
            print("Nothing pressed")
        return {'FINISHED'}
        
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(myPanel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(myModalOperator)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(myPanel)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(myModalOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```
````

Comment: try adding _if event.value == "PRESS":_ below _if event.type == "RIGHTMOUSE;"_ (Indented, of course) before calling the print function and see if that makes it return anything.

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately this didn't return anything after I added it either.